# CPU fans not working on Dell laptop running Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, cpu, fan

The CPU fans are not working at all on my DELL Inspiron 15R N5110, I am running Ubuntu 20.04.2 Server, and the laptop overheats quickly after a small duration of uptime.

I checked the hardware and the fans seems okay.
Also before I uninstalled windows 7, the fans were working okay, so I know it is not a hardware problem.

This is the output of `pwmwconfig` from `fancotrol`:

```
# pwmconfig version 3.6.0
This program will search your sensors for pulse width modulation (pwm)
controls, and test each one to see if it controls a fan on
your motherboard. Note that many motherboards do not have pwm
circuitry installed, even if your sensor chip supports pwm.

We will attempt to briefly stop each fan using the pwm controls.
The program will attempt to restore each fan to full speed
after testing. However, it is ** very important ** that you
physically verify that the fans have been to full speed
after the program has completed.

Found the following devices:
   hwmon0 is AC
   hwmon1 is acpitz
   hwmon2 is BAT0
   hwmon3 is nouveau
   hwmon4 is coretemp
   hwmon5 is dell_smm

Found the following PWM controls:
   hwmon5/pwm1           current value: 255

Giving the fans some time to reach full speed...
Found the following fan sensors:
   hwmon5/fan1_input     current speed: 0 ... skipping!

There are no working fan sensors, all readings are 0.
Make sure you have a 3-wire fan connected.
You may also need to increase the fan divisors.
See doc/fan-divisors for more information.
```

Comment: Just in case (undo whatever was done and) have a look there: https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/i8kutils . Debian offers a longer description: "
Fan control for Dell laptops

This is a collection of utilities to control Dell laptops fans. It includes programs to turn the fans on and off, to read fans status, CPU temperature, BIOS version. "